# Under what kind of set defintion, a, b will be constrained by a+b=c?

Tags: group-theory, arithmetic

This is a soft question, but my mind has been struggling with it these days...(I'm reading Munkres' General Topology and doing Integer Programming with Gurobi)

Suppose $a, b, c \in A $ and $a+b=c$ holds.

When A is the set of real numbers (i.e., $A=\mathbb{R}$), then $a, b$ can be any real numbers if $c$'s value is not constrained.

When A is the set of integers (i.e., $A=\mathbb{Z}$), then $a, b$ can be any integers if $c$'s value is not constrained.

...etc

However, when $A =\{0,1\}$, then $a, b$ **cannot** be both 1 even if $c$ is not constrained.

So my question is, under what kind definition of $A$, there will certain constraints on $a, b$ even if $c$ is free.

Comment: You are asking for a set where you can add any two elements. That's called a semigroup...

Comment: In your last example, if we are using the addition in mod 2, a and b can both be 1, which gives a+b=0. So in some sense at least, it depends on how you define the addition (operation) in your set A.

Comment: @DonThousand The set being a semigroup is sufficient but unnecessary for such constraints to be absent; see my answer.

Comment: Thank Divide, very interesting insight, I never thought about mod in this way.

Answer (score 0):

As @DonThousand notes, such a constraint exists iff $A$ is not [closed under](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(mathematics)) addition, i.e. does not form a [*magma*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magma_(algebra)) under $+$. @Divide1918 observes that $\{0,\,1\}$ forms a magma under modulo-$2$ addition, but not under "ordinary" addition.

Comment: Thank you very much! I got the idea of "closed" under addition with modulo. And I am wondering the opposite situation: creating some non-closed situations deliberately to raise desirable constraints. Are there such  non-closed cases in number theory or group theory?

Comment: @whitegreen Just about any $(S,\,\oplus)$ with $\oplus$ binary on $S$ is not a magma, unless it's obvious why it is one. Of course, to prove it's not one you just need an example where $x,\,y\in S,\,x\oplus y\notin S$.